# Calling method from a different class

Tags: ruby

I'm having trouble understanding these lines of code in the Exercise 43 of the book *Learn Ruby the hard way*. Hoping someone would explain it to me.

In the while loop of the method play(), which method is being executed if the while statement is true? Are **next_scene_name** and **current_scene** just variables being defined? And they are being defined by running the **opening_scene** method which is a method from a different class (class Map), class Engine and class Map have no relation to each other (do they?) how could something in class Engine call a method in class Map?

```
class Engine

  def initialize(scene_map)
    @scene_map = scene_map
  end

  def play()
    current_scene = @scene_map.opening_scene()
    last_scene = @scene_map.next_scene('finished')

    while current_scene != last_scene
      next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
      current_scene = @scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)
    end

    # be sure to print out the last scene
    current_scene.enter()
  end
end

class Map
  @@scenes = {
    'central_corridor' => CentralCorridor.new(),
    'laser_weapon_armory' => LaserWeaponArmory.new(),
    'the_bridge' => TheBridge.new(),
    'escape_pod' => EscapePod.new(),
    'death' => Death.new(),
    'finished' => Finished.new(),
  }


  def initialize(start_scene)
    @start_scene = start_scene
  end


  def next_scene(scene_name)
    val = @@scenes[scene_name]
    return val
  end

  def opening_scene()
    return next_scene(@start_scene)
  end
end
```

Comment: Your assumptions are all correct. But why do you think an `Engine` shouldn't be allowed to call a method on a `Map`? The `scene_map` was passed into the `Engine` during initialization (aka the instance is known to the engine) and the `opening_scene` and the `next_scene` methods are not `private` in the Map class.

Comment: OK, I didn't know I could call a method in a different class, I was not aware of public and private methods feature. You cleared up a lot for me, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two types of methods and variables to be aware of.

**Class** methods can be called without declaring an instance of a class.

**Instance** methods can only be called on an instance of a class.

Example:

```
class Car
  @@number_of_cars_in_existence = 0

  def self.count_all_cars_in_existence
    @@number_of_cars_in_existence
  end

  def paint_red
    @color = red
  end
end
```

Here, any other class, say, the `bureaucrat` class can count all the cars in existence with `Car.count_all_cars_in_existence`, however, to call a `paint_red` method, they must call the method of an individual car.

```
class StackOverflowPerson
  def paint_car(car)
    car.paint_red
  end
end

trajanson = StackOverflowPerson.new
my_car = Car.new
trajanson.paint_car(my_car)
```

Comment: Do you refer to class methods, when you say `Public methods can be called without declaring an instance of a class` ? Class methods also can be public/private/protected.

Answer (score 0):

Your question quite complicated and simple in the same time.
Let's start from:

```
def initialize(scene_map) # seems like `scene_map` is an instance of class Map
  @scene_map = scene_map
end
```

Then we have method that call public methods for given instance (at `@scene_map`):

```
def play()
  current_scene = @scene_map.opening_scene() # here
  last_scene = @scene_map.next_scene('finished') # and here

  while current_scene != last_scene
    next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
    current_scene = @scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name) #and here
  end

  # be sure to print out the last scene
  current_scene.enter()
end
```

Comment: How is `scene_map` an instance of the Map class? There is no `scene_map` mentioned in Map class. I thought it's just a common declaration of the instance variable when Map.new() is called.

Comment: I found this at the source of the exercise: `a_map = Map.new('central_corridor'); a_game = Engine.new(a_map)`. You initialize new `Engine` with the instance of `Map`. So scene_map is just a variable that refers to that instance.